# Installation elementary OS 0.4

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install elementary 0.4 I already have 0.3.2. I went to the elementary web site, I contributed and asked for download but when I check if it has been downloaded its not there. What am I doing wrong, or is this a problem on their end. Answer for an estreme Newbie

Comment: Are you seeing this popup? http://i.stack.imgur.com/6PHxZ.png What browser/os are you using?

Comment: No I am not seeing any popup, I am using Chromium of elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya (32-bit)

Comment: It's possible an extension you have installed is interfering. Does it work with them disabled (incognito mode does this by default)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to http://elementary.io
2. Click the blue "Purchase/Download elementary OS" button [image: elementary.io]
3. Click "Download Loki" (not the magnet icon, which starts a magnetized torrent download) [image: Download Loki]

The disk image should download to your normal downloads folder.

From there you can follow the install directions at https://elementary.io/docs/installation